# textBox get focus

Tags: windows-phone-7

I hope to make TextBox get focus when a page display.
I wrote:

```
protected override void onManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedArgs e)
{

    textBox1.Focus();
    base.onManipulationStarted(  e);

}
```

but there is nothing happned

Welcome any comment

Comment: What control is causing that `Manipulation` event and does the `Focus()` code get fired? If you want to do it after the page has loaded, you can handle the page's `Loaded` event and put the `textBox1.Focus();` statement there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want set the focus when page loaded, you have to add the event handler on the event of **Loaded** of the page.

Write the

> textBox1.Focus();

code in the loaded event handler in page.xaml.cs